# Ionic 4 PWA Angular 8 - unable to fetch start URL via service worker error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, angular8, angular-service-worker

I am attempting to setup PWA on my ionic 4 application however i get an error like this below when auditing with lighthouse in chrome.

[image]

I followed the tutorial on this link [create-an-ionic-4-pwa-with-capacitor](https://blog.jscrambler.com/create-an-ionic-4-pwa-with-capacitor/)

I cloned their project and it seems to be working on my local but i can't seem to figure out the difference with my app.

I would like to see the ***add to home screen*** panel at the bottom but it seems it will not show if i don't fix this error.

What i already tried:

- Deploying on https server
- forcing service worker enabled to true in app.module `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true })`

However it did not fix it. Last thing i can do is downgrading to angular 7.2 if i cannot really find a way.

my version of angular and ionic are the latest which is listed below:

- "@angular/pwa": "^0.801.1",
- "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
- "@ionic/angular": "^4.6.2",
- "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",

manifest.webmanifest content:

```
"display": "standalone",
"scope": "/",
"start_url": "/",
```

**[UPDATE]**

i tried downgrading to angular 7.2 and it seems working now. However if someone can answer if how to make it work in angular 8 that will be great

Answer (score 3):

It seems the issue was not with angular 8 as i have tried creating a new app from scratch and it worked. However i have found a solution in my case.

there is a property called `registrationStrategy` when registering a serviceworker in app.module.ts. By default it has a value of `registerWhenStable`. The fix was changing this to `registerImmediately`

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })
```

Here are the possible values for that based on its source code

[image]

So my app is somehow not stable enough on first load reason why the service worker did not run properly which i need to investigate. Posting it here hopefully it will help somebody.